# onContentAfterSave doesn't show custom fields

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, custom-field, system-plugin

I created a plugin to send published articles data to external service

```
class plgSystemVacancypub extends JPlugin
{
    public function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
      // Get custom fields values
      $customFieldnames = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article->get('id'), true);
      $customFieldIds   = array_map(create_function('$o', 'return $o->id;'), $customFieldnames);
      $fmodel           = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Field', 'FieldsModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
      $customFieldValues= $fmodel->getFieldValues($customFieldIds , $article->get('id')); 
       

      // Send to external function
    }
}
```

But in my article I have some custom fields. First saving the article the `$customFieldValues` variable is empty. And when I click to Save article once again, custom fields are exists.
As I know the custom fields saves after article saving. How can I replace the subsequence of executing "save the custom fields" and my plugin? I want to see custom fields values on first publishing of article.

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer, and I don't fully understand the question.  But perhaps you can watch this video.  It might be that you are hooking onto the plugin system at the wrong time.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_agXP5DHm_g

Comment: If simple, I need first save custom fields values of article, then execute my plugin (in which I use custom fields values).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't found the solution to my problem.
But I found another way - correcting the fields plugin (`plugins/fields/fields.php`), which saves custom fields after article saved.
Now I have access to values of all custom fields of first time saving article in `onContentAfterSave` function.

Answer (score 0):

That event has an undocumented aditional argument `$data` which holds the saved data!

```
public function onContentAfterSave($context, $item, $isNew, $data = []){

}
```

Just in case, set its default to an empty array.

If you check your custom field in the `$data` it will be there after the event is fired.

For example, for a standard field like the tags, just get them like this:

```
$thetagssaved = $data['tags'];
```

For a custom field named "myfield", get it like this:

```
$myfieldvalue = $data['com_fields']['myfield'];
```

If you have doubts on what you need to get, output the `$data` into your log:

```
error_log(print_r($data, true));
```